# не получается получить imei

Tags: java, android

Не получается получить imei телефона. Отсюда пару вопросов собственно говоря...

Для информации, андроид 10 (ориг.) + рут, через Magisk, не более.

Собственно пытался так (а так и должно работать...):

```
 TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(this.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
 
 String imeiNumber2 = tm.getImei(1); //двухсимочный тел. , нужен imei 2
```

в манифесте разрешение READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE есть

Всё дело творю под виндой в андроид студии разумеется.

и так... теперь сами проблемы...
Ставлю приложение, запускаю и в логах в андроид студии следующее:

eException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: getImeiForSlot: The user 10171 does not meet the requirements to access device identifiers.

На сколько я понял - мне нужны системные права, тут два варианта которые я узнал: поместить приложение в папку /system/app из папки /data/app собственно, что я и сделал имея рут. Но... результат такой же.... не работает, хотя при удалении через настройки на телефоне сразу видно, что приложение стало системным, так как кнопки удалить не стало, только остановить.

Т.е. оно системное но imei не получить, происходит выкидыш и в логах выше сказанная ошибка, мол пользователь прав не имеет...

Другой вариант это подписать системным сертификатом приложение (надеюсь поможет) и тут... вопрос... как? как это в андроид студии сделать? где вообще найти системный сертификат на телефоне.... если это выход их ситуации и imei можно будет получить, то подскажите как подписать системным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ладно... решил иначе, так как есть рут... тооо вот решение:

```
imei1:

/system/bin/service call iphonesubinfo 3 i32 1 | cut -d\' -f2 | sed -e 's/[^0-9]//g' | tr -d '\n'

imei2:
/system/bin/service call iphonesubinfo 3 i32 2 | cut -d\' -f2 | sed -e 's/[^0-9]//g' | tr -d '\n'
```

использовал в приложении так (на примере первого imei):

```
Process processx1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "/system/bin/service call iphonesubinfo 3 i32 1 | cut -d\\' -f2 | sed -e 's/[^0-9]//g' | tr -d '\\n'"});
BufferedReader in1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(processx1.getInputStream()));
String line1 = null;
while ((line1 = in1.readLine()) != null) {
IMEI1 = line1;
}
processx1.waitFor();
```

да... не православно может... может не стильно, не модно.. но никак иначе, как через рут не удалось получить результат.

Системные права вообще шл.па.
Как я нагуглил... теперь в андроидах (от 10го и плюс) вообще imei не получить, ну вот только через рут и якобы через системные права (сертификат прошивки я не нашёл... а перенос приложения в /system/app хоть и сделал его системным.. но задачу не помог решить, поэтому через рут, через консоль...)